# jQuery uncheck all if "ALL" selected

Tags: jquery, html

I have a range of checkboxes which are generated based on options from a table in my database. I want to create a default checkbox in that range called "VIEW ALL" which when checked, should uncheck all of the other checkboxes, but if any of the checkboxes within the range is checked, it should keep all existing ones but uncheck the "VIEW ALL" checkbox.

Sample HTML:

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="attr[1][]" class="attr" value="ALL" checked />VIEW ALL
 <input type="checkbox" name="attr[1][]" class="attr" value="2" /> VALUE 2
 <input type="checkbox" name="attr[1][]" class="attr" value="5" /> VALUE 5
 <input type="checkbox" name="attr[1][]" class="attr" value="6" /> VALUE 6
```

Sample jQuery:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    // CATEGORY SELECTOR TO ADD ADDITIONAL CONTROLS:
    $(".attr").on("change",function() {
        var name = $(this).attr("name");
        var val = $(this).val();
        if(val === "ALL") {
            $(name).each(function(k,v) {
               $(this).removeAttr("checked"); 
            });
        } else {

        }
    });
});
</script>
```

At this stage, nothing happens, it does not even unselect the ALL one. Any ideas or advice would greatly be appreciated.

Here is a jsfiddle for testing purposes: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p51d0db1/2/)

Comment: cycle over all .attr instead and check the one with all afterwards again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as below:

HTML

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="attr[1][]" class="attr" value="ALL" />VIEW ALL

 $(document).ready(function() {

    // CATEGORY SELECTOR TO ADD ADDITIONAL CONTROLS:

    $(".attr").on("change",function() {
        var name = $(this).attr("name");
        var val = $(this).val();
        if(val === "ALL") {
            $('input[name^= "attr"]').prop('checked',$(this).is(":checked"));
        }
    });
});
```

[DeMO](http://jsfiddle.net/p51d0db1/4/)

Comment: and by the way. value all is always true if you change the all checkbox (even when you uncheck it).

Comment: @Andi need to write code, It is for all check box only

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, what OP wants is either VIEW ALL is selected or any of the other is selected.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply check if it is "ALL" and uncheck all excluding "VIEW ALL" checkbox and do vice versa in the else loop. See my demo below,

**PS:** I have added a class `.all` to the VIEW ALL checkbox for easy selecting.

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p51d0db1/9/)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    // CATEGORY SELECTOR TO ADD ADDITIONAL CONTROLS:
    var $checkboxes = $('.attr');
    $(".attr").on("change", function () {
        if (this.checked && this.value == 'ALL') { //all is checked
            $checkboxes.not(this).prop('checked', false);
        } else { //some other is checked or unchecked
            $('.attr.all').prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="attr[1][]" class="attr all" value="ALL" checked />VIEW ALL
<input type="checkbox" name="attr[1][]" class="attr" value="2" />VALUE 2
<input type="checkbox" name="attr[1][]" class="attr" value="5" />VALUE 5
<input type="checkbox" name="attr[1][]" class="attr" value="6" />VALUE 6
```

Comment: Great solution and use of .not(this)